# HTML Table Change Row to Column For loop

Tags: php, html, html-table

I need to attach two tables.
First loop is perfect,
but second For-loop table goes to the Bottom.
I need to attach that bottom table to that  previous one.
Can anyone please solve this problem?
Any Solution would be appreciated, so suggest something to solve this.

```
<?php
    include 'pappu.php';
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
    header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    $grab=ngegrab('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets/USDT');
    $json = json_decode($grab, true);
    $usd= $json['Data'][3]['AskPrice'];
    $grabb=ngegrab('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets/USDT');
    $jsonss = json_decode($grabb, true);
    $dogeusd= $jsonss['Data'][8]['AskPrice'];
    $grabsz=ngegrab('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets/DOGE');
    $jsonsz = json_decode($grabsz);
    $grabs=ngegrab('https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetMarkets/BTC');
    $jsons = json_decode($grabs);
    echo "<table border=1>";
    echo "<th>BTC EXCHANGE</th>";
    if($jsons)
        foreach ($jsons->Data as $sam){
            $market= $sam->Label . "\n";
            $link= $sam->AskPrice . "\n";
            echo "<tr><td>$market</td>";
            $link = number_format($link, 8);
            echo "<td>$link" ;
            echo '($'; 
            echo number_format($link * $usd, 6) ;
            echo ')';
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
    echo "<th>DOGE EXCHANGE</th>";
    foreach ($jsonsz->Data as $sam){
        $market= $sam->Label . "\n";
        $link= $sam->AskPrice . "\n";
        echo "<tr><td>$market</td>";
        $link = number_format($link, 8);
        echo "<td>$link" ;
        echo '($'  ; 
        echo number_format($link * $dogeusd, 6) ;
        echo ')';
        echo "</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Please provide `JSON` and Expected result format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First set the table headers (`<th>`), then set the table body if you want all the headers to appear inline.

You can then make arrays for the rows of the two tables and just output for each row.

**Note:** In case your `$btc` and `$doge` arrays have a different amount of rows or are not in the same order you then might have to create a third array by combining the two, then loop over that.

```
echo '<table border="1">
      <tr>
          <th colspan="2">BTC EXCHANGE</th>
          <th colspan="2">DOGE EXCHANGE</th>
      </tr>';

// prepare the rows
$btc = array();
$doge = array();

if($jsons)
{
  foreach ($jsons->Data as $sam)
  {
     $number = (float) $sam->AskPrice;
     array_push($btc, array($sam->Label, number_format($number,8) ));
  }

  foreach ($jsonsz->Data as $sam)
  {
     $number = (float) $sam->AskPrice;
     array_push($doge, array($sam->Label, number_format($number,8) ));
  }

  // assuming count($btc) and count($doge) are the same
  for($i=0; $i< count($btc); $i++)
  {
      echo '<tr>
             <td>'.$btc[i][0].'</td>
             <td>'.$btc[i][1].' ($'.number_format($btc[i][1] * $usd, 6).')</td>
             <td>'.$doge[i][0].'</td>
             <td>'.$doge[i][1].' ($'.number_format($doge[i][1] * $usd, 6).')</td> 
          </tr>';
  }
}
echo '</table>';
?>
```

Comment: can you please do this `print_r($btc);` and show what it outputs, just to see if the array is populated at all. Add that after `</table>`.

Comment: Ok, so the array is populated. How many decimals do you get from the json?

Comment: up to 0.00000000

Comment: hm, i will edit to include `(float)`, it seems your numbers contain non number characters.

Comment: ya you can ignore that :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two `<th>` cells which should be in a table row `<tr>`:

```
echo "<th>BTC EXCHANGE</th>";
```

and

```
echo "<th>DOGE EXCHANGE</th>";
```

Change your code to:

```
echo "<tr><th>BTC EXCHANGE</th></tr>";
```

and

```
echo "<tr><th>DOGE EXCHANGE</th>";
```